# Add a button after Create and Import in odoo v11

Tags: listview, button, odoo-11

I search a lot in the web, read the odoo docs, but I can't figure it out how to add a button before "Create" and "Import" buttons. I found many solutions in other versions (v8, v9 and v10) but none works.

The result should look like this. And the buttons have access to python functions.

link to image: [ibb.co/gACTSc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElDH4.png)

Comment: Why would you like to do that? You can add actions to the "Actions" menu or you can add buttons to the form. If you adapt your needs to the Odoo Framework then it is going to be easier for you

Comment: I know right? but my boss want it in that way u.u
So I'm looking for a way without touching the core files of odoo

Comment: haha tell him that it´s not possible and you will save time. Anyway I think it´s not worth it to change the default behaviour